# PHP PDO Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

running into a problem which i don't appear to see.

here's my function

```
function addIT($type, $amount, $id) {
$db = new database();
$conn8 = $db->connect();
$addit = $conn8->prepare("UPDATE accountTable SET :type = :type + :amount WHERE ID =     :id");
$addit->execute(array('type'=>$type, 'amount'=>$amount, 'id'=>$id));
}
```

heres the call i make:

```
$type = "age";
$amount = 17;
$id = 1;
addIT($type, $amount, $id);
```

now when execute the code it gives me below error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''age' = 'age' + '17' WHERE ID = '1'' at line 1' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/me/functions/activity.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/me/functions/activity.php(7): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/me/content/doadd.php(66): addIT('age', 17, '1') #2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/me/main(48): include('/Library/WebSer...') #3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/me/where.php(25): include('/Library/WebSer...') #4 {main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/me/functions/activity.php on line 7
```

i'm sure theres something wrong in my execute or prepare statement. i dont see it anymore.

Comment: You can't have variable column or table names in your query

Comment: There shouldn't be $conn8 variable at all. As well as any other $connN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function addIT($conn, $type, $amount, $id)
{
    $allowed = array('age','sex','whatever');
    if (!in_array($type,$allowed))
    {
         throw new Exception("Invalid type");
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE accountTable SET `$type` = `$type` + :amount WHERE ID = :id"
    $stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array('amount'=>$amount, 'id'=>$id));
}
```

Comment: perfect workaround! works aswell. And because i'm looking for a dynamic solution, this fits my question best.

Comment: They should really have a feature in PDO for this very thing because these work-arounds are always super worrying.

Comment: true, kinda takes away the safety PDO should bring

Comment: This is not of PDO responsibility but rather some sort of ACL - to decide which fields to update we have to know the application logic, of which PDO cannot be aware

Answer (score 4):

You can't have variable column or table names in your query. Use

```
UPDATE accountTable 
SET age = age + :amount 
WHERE ID = :id
```

BTW you should not store the age of a person but rather the birthdate. Then you don't have to update that.